# Can rotations in a plane be described in terms of plane polar coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, rotations

It makes sense to talk about rotation through an angle $\theta$ in a plane in terms of Cartesian coordinates, and it can also be quantified as the matrix transformation $$\begin{pmatrix}x^\prime\\ y^\prime\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\phi & \sin\phi\\-\sin\phi & \cos\phi\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}.$$

Can one describe a rotation in a plane in terms of plane polar coordinates? If yes, how? Sorry if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Just add the rotation angle to $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{pmatrix}\rho\\ \theta^\prime\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\rho\\ \theta_0\end{pmatrix} +\begin{pmatrix}0\\ \theta\end{pmatrix}$$

Where $\rho$ is the length of the given vector, $\theta_0$ is the angle of the given vector, $\theta$ is the angle of rotation, and $\theta^\prime$ is the angle of the given vector after rotation.

Comment: What is the corresponding rotation matrix? @WaveX

Comment: If you want to look at it using a rotation matrix it would be:
$$\begin{pmatrix}\rho\\ \theta^\prime\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & \theta'/\theta_0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\rho\\ \theta_0\end{pmatrix}$$
That is, to create the rotation matrix, you would need to know the angle you want the vector to be at after the rotation, not necessarily how many degrees / radians you want to rotate the matrix.